Jenkins multibranch pipeline environment variables CHANGE_TITLE and CHANGE_ID are null
I have a Jenkins multibranch pipeline job, that runs every time a PR opens for a repository.
I want to be able to get the PR title/name.
The GitHub Branch Source Plugin is installed and in the most recent version.
However, the following env vars are returned null:

CHANGE_ID
CHANGE_URL
CHANGE_TITLE

How can I get the PR title?
